# What is the status of gravitational wave searches?

Tags: gravitational-waves, ligo

What is the status of gravitational wave searches such as [LIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO)?

Comment: Any particular aspect of the searches you're interested in? What experiments exist, or which ones are planned, or what they have detected, or ruled out...? This is kind of a broad question as is (though it is a good thing to ask about).

Comment: The status is that no gravitational waves have been detected yet.  Is that all you want to know?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10161/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18500/2451

Comment: (Advanced) LIGO has officially announced detection of gravitational waves (as per 11 February 2016).