# Gravitational waves detection, any news?

Tags: experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, ligo

Is the detection of [gravitational waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) a reality with nowadays technology? 
Are there recent news?

Comment: I see there was a question very similar to this. Sorry. It looks like there are no (detectable) gravity waves yet, out there. Correct ?

Comment: If there were, it would be covered in the news by a bunch of journalists who have no clue what they're talking about.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): It seems this post is conflating [gravity waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) and [gravitational waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave). Related for the latter: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10161/2451

Comment: (Advanced) LIGO has, on 11 February 2016, announced detection of gravitational waves from a binary black hole merger with more than $5\sigma$ certainty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately gravitational waves have not been detected yet.

There is a number of Earth-bound detectors planned and already in operation (e.g. [LIGO](http://ligonews.blogspot.com/), [Geo 600](http://www.geo600.org/), [Virgo](https://wwwcascina.virgo.infn.it/), [Nanograv](http://nanograv.org/) and [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave_detector)). As for space-borne detectors, ESA works on [Next Gravitational-Wave Observatory](http://science.nasa.gov/media/medialibrary/2011/07/21/7132011_ESAs_NGO-Stebbins.pdf) after NASA [pulled out](http://news.discovery.com/space/a-farewell-to-lisa-110408.html) of [LISA](http://sci.esa.int/science-e/www/area/index.cfm?fareaid=27) project in April 2011 due to funding problems. Joint NASA/ESA mission, [LISA Pathfinder](http://www.esa.int/SPECIALS/Operations/SEMR4E7DWZE_0.html) will launch in June 2013 testing technologies to be used by NGO.

Keep an eye on the pages and blogs of these projects if you'd like to stay up to date on their progress. Also, if gravitational waves are detected, the discovery will no doubt be announced [here](http://www.nature.com/news/) and even [here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/).

Comment: @Zalcman: thank you for your comprehensive answer. I will keep an eye on the institutions you listed.

Comment: Maybe we should update this answer with the correct one?