# How would gravitons be detected?

Tags: gravity, quantum-gravity, particle-detectors

How would gravitons be detected indirectly or directly, in space or on earth? And what experiments are going on to find gravitons?

Comment: Good question. You might find http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/34118/what-is-the-likelihood-of-ever-discovering-the-graviton interesting

Comment: @HDE226868 so would you consider this question a duplicate?

Comment: It's pretty close to one.

Comment: @HDE226868 should I delete my question?

Comment: Up to you. Personally, I'd wait for an opinion from someone more qualified that me, and not delete it.