# Why is graviton not found yet?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, experimental-physics, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves

Why is graviton not found yet? Newton said gravity pulls us, Einstein said space is bent and it pushes us, hawking predicts the existence of graviton and 'hawking radiation'. How far are we from knowing every tits and bits of gravity? Is graviton real or just imagination?

Comment: Sorry... don't have a working crystal ball at the moment. How would we know the future? What is the graviton today? It's an oversimplified toy model, at best, that comes from the (logically questionable) application of lessons learned about the other forces to the non-force gravity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the likelihood of ever discovering the graviton?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34118/)

Comment: Thanx prahar...but if they are so hard to detect how did they came to be known??

Comment: We never can know unless we can ask from creator of the world and I think no one can talk with that.

Comment: @user113241: Because it is not necessary to detect a single graviton to be able to see its effects. Take electromagnetism, where its properties were known long before the photon was even 'invented' (QED) much less seen in detectors.