# Are there other places to look for the gravitational wave, other than space?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, gravitational-waves

The recent BICEP2 announcements about the existence of gravity waves made the news, and made a big pitch for cosmic inflation, in the process they also claimed to detect the existence of gravitational waves. Have the results of the experiment been validated? Have they been confirmed by the European counterparts? If not would there be other ways to look for the gravitational wave- are there any lab experiments that could prove/disprove its existence?

Answer (score 2):

Since the original BICEP2 publication there has been increasing suspicions that what they had seen was actually just a signal from interstellar dust. We've been waiting for data from the Planck experiment on the dust signal, and that data has just been released. Sadly it looks as if BICEP2 did indeed [just see dust and not signals from gravitational waves](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2014/sep/22/bicep2-gravitational-wave-result-bites-the-dust-thanks-to-new-planck-data).

All is not yet lost. The BICEP team plan to improve their experiment and evidence for gravitational waves may still emerge. However it's currently looking as if they've just added another entry to the list of failed GW experiments.

There's a good review of terrestrial GW detection experiments in the answers to [Is there a good chance that gravitational waves will be detected in the next years?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10161/is-there-a-good-chance-that-gravitational-waves-will-be-detected-in-the-next-yea).