# How strong were the gravitational waves that LIGO detected at the source?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, experimental-physics, gravitational-waves, ligo

Congrats to the LIGO team on the announcement of their discovery of gravitational waves!

The articles I've read say that the distortion we see here is much smaller than a proton. What about at the source? Would these waves have been strong enough to see macroscopic effects near the binary black holes themselves? Could you orbit the system at a "safe" distance, observe the merger, and "feel" the waves?

Comment: We are "orbiting" at a safe distance, aren't we? What's a macroscopic effect for you? Obviously the effect here was still macroscopic enough to see it, wasn't it? Is there a distance at which you could feel the wave in your stomach? Probably... not sure it would be safe for other reasons, though. At that distance the gravity would certainly not do more to you than the acceleration in a roller coaster. Having said that, the frequency at which LIGO made the detection will probably not be near the peak sensitivity of your stomach.

Comment: http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102

Comment: the press conference has nice videos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_582rU6neLc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the press announcement, the merger of the black holes released an amount of energy equivalent to three solar masses (an energy given by $E=mc^{2}$ with $m$ being three times the mass of the sun), which is an absolutely mind-boggling amount of energy.  If you were too close, the rapidly fluctuating [tidal forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) on your body would cause alternating compressive and tensile stresses on your body, tearing your body to bits, which would certainly count as a "macroscopic effect".

Sure, at an appropriate distance, you'd still be able to feel the gravitational wave without being killed.  However, with such an enormous amount of energy being released from two objects that are quite small and close together by astronomical standards, for the experience to be survivable you'd have to be so far away that you wouldn't really be able to "observe the merger" with the naked eye.  I.e., you wouldn't be able to see two black blobs in the sky that merge into one.

Comment: Why would you be vaporized? Wasn't this energy released as gravitational waves?

Comment: @MichaelT Good point.  After the rapidly fluctuating tidal forces tore your body to pieces, the pieces would perhaps then be too small for the tidal forces on them to generate enough heat from friction to cause vaporization.  I didn't do a detailed calculation.  I have change my answer's cause of death accordingly.

Comment: If you only have distortions of ≈1% in a distance of ≈1000km I don't think that you would have to be so far away that you couldn't see anything with the naked eye to survive the event. It also does not matter how much energy is involved, what matters is the power (energy per time).

Comment: @СимонТыран The power was clearly also enormous, given that all that energy was released in less than half a second.

Comment: To be fair to @СимонТыран, that power wasn't angled in one direction. So I guess it's not just the energy or the power, it's the intensity.

Comment: @СимонТыран If you try to stretch a bone in a few milliseconds such that the bone is "only" 1% longer than it normally is, the bone is going to snap. If you try to squeeze a skull in a few milliseconds to be "only" 1% narrower than it normally is, that's likely to be fatal.  A uniform 1% strain on a human body is a lot.

Comment: Since I don't know much about medicine I have to grant you that point, but when gravitational waves decrease with 1/r I still think that you don't have to be incredibly far from the event to not get killed.

Comment: This sounds like a good subject for XKCD's "What If?" feature.

Comment: @MichaelT there's quite likely to be a bunch of other energy released - e.g. a gamma ray burst - from the incredibly violent interaction, which is going to do bad things to you.

Comment: Leaving aside the non-gravitational effects, what would the momentum transfer due to the passage of the wave be? Say at 100,000 km, where the strain is only 0.01%, so presumably nothing held together by ordinary solid state forces gets torn apart? You've got 3 solar masses of energy-momentum flowing outward... Is there some sort of "immaculate" momentum transfer to a nearby object, where it gets a boost without feeling much of anything by the wave's passage?

Comment: I wonder about this. According to one source I found, the peak power emitted was over $3 \times 10^{49}$ watts -- which at a distance of 100,000 _light years_ would come to about 2.9 megawatts per square meter. Any idea what that would do to a human body at that distance? I know if that were EM radiation, you'd be roasted. But gravitational waves? I also note the gravity of the black holes on their own, no merger, would be imperceptibly slight at that distance as well...

Answer (score 39):

The strain (ratio of displacement from equilibrium to equilibrium separation) of gravitational waves decreases as $1/r$ for a distance $r$ from the source. Since the strain in this case peaked at $10^{-21}$ at a distance of $1.3\times10^9\ \mathrm{ly} = 1.3\times10^{25}\ \mathrm{m}$, you would expect strains on the order of $1\%$ at a distance of $1300\ \mathrm{km}$. For reference, the observed signal is from black holes that were about $100\ \mathrm{km}$ in radius initially.

Much closer than this, and the linearized theory of GR breaks down. Gravitational waves are only well-defined in the small-amplitude limit. Close-in, we have the near-field regime where nonlinear effects that can't really be described as simple waves dominate. The only simple statement that really can be made here is that distortions are even stronger closer in.

Comment: Is this how they estimated the distance of the event? By comparing the observed strain to what computer models using GR predict by looking at waveform?

Comment: @dualredlaugh Yes, exactly.

Comment: So at 1300km, I'd be shrinking and growing + or - 1% of my height, basically?

Comment: @John : You're slightly more squishy.

Comment: @John Freely floating objects would move that way, if you factor in the frequency, you can find the effective force (calculate the acceleration), which is then proportional to the mass. Your body will experience this effective force.

Answer (score 6):

Knowing that the emitted energy is of about 3 solar masses, and if we use the famous Einstein energy formula $E=mc^2$ we have then :

$\text{A.N.:}\ \ E=1,989\cdot10^{30} \times 3 \times c^2\approx2\cdot10^{43} \ \text{J}$

which is a huge amount of energy. This is a bigger emission of energy than a supernova (!) and similar to gamma-ray bursts (biggest emission of light after the Big-Bang)...

[image]

Making "popular science", this is the caloric intake (energy) that $5\cdot10^{34}$ Nutella pots of 400kg would give you.

If that amount of energy would be inside the gravitational waves passing threw us, we would be looking like spaghettis. Our body and Earth would be visibly distorted or elongated. Maybe the word "feel" is not appropriate because it would be more "die". Orbiting the system at a safe distance is plausible, knowing that we have to take care the combined ISCO (innermost stable circular orbit or last stable orbit) of both black holes before they merge. 
We can determine it by :

$R_{ISCO} = \dfrac{6GM}{c^2}$

where $M$ is the mass of the black hole in $kg$ and $G$ the universal gravitational constant in $N\cdot m^2\cdot kg^{-2}$ and $c$ the velocity of light in $m\cdot s^{-1}$. We then have, for the most massive black hole (here $36$ solar masses) :

$R_{ISCO} = \dfrac{6\times6,67384\cdot10^{-11}\times36\times1,989\cdot10^{30}}{299 792 458^2}=319,0\cdot10^3m=319,0km$

For the ring-down black hole of $62$ solar masses, we have ${{R}_{rd}}_{ISCO}=5,494\cdot10^5m=549,4km$

[image]

Comment: My back-of-envelope calculation has the energy of the black hole event roughly matching the nutritional energy of enough Nutella to fill the orbit of Venus.

Comment: That doesn't seem right... 3 solar masses' worth of E=MC^2? Only enough nutella to fill the orbit of Venus?