# How far gravitational waves like the ones recently detecty are dangerous for life?

Tags: gravitational-waves

I have read that gravitational waves can tear matter appart. I imagine you have to be fairly close to the event to be affected. Do we have a rough estimation of lethal distance ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How close would you have to be to the merger of two black holes, for the effects ...](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/168274/) or [LIGO event - energies involved?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235605/), or [How strong were the gravitational waves that LIGO detected at the source?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235285/)

Comment: They have to be very very strong for that scenario and we would not need LIGO to detect them. There may be other problems that will impact life in that case.