# What would the effects of the GW150914 gravity wave burst be on observers much closer that 1.3B LY?

Tags: gravity, waves, black-holes, ligo

The effects of the GW150914 gravity wave burst were barely observable with state of the art instruments, i.e. LIGO. What would the effects of  GW150914 gravity wave burst be on observers much closer that 1.3B LY? For example, in the same galaxy 30,000 LY from the black hole merger. Or on a planet orbiting a few dozen AU from the event.
I have read that the wave contained energy equivalent (in the MC^2 sense) to three solar masses. How is this energy transferred to a nearby planet?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235285/how-strong-were-the-gravitational-waves-that-ligo-detected-at-the-source